# LinkedList stuck in infinite loop. Try to get next Node

Tags: java, loops, infinite, nodelist

While trying to get the next node in the `LinkedList`, it gets stuck in a infinite loop. It's not grabbing a new one.

Apparantly, I'm not calling `getNext()` on the next item, I'm  calling it on the first node, so it only returns the second node.

Any help is appreciated.

```
    public static final GroundItem[] getGroundItemsAt(final int x, final int y) {
    try {
        final Object deque = Game.getGroundItems()[Game.getPlane()][x][y];

        if (deque == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Deque deq = new Deque(deque);
        ArrayList<GroundItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Object holder = deq.getHead();
        Node hold = new Node(holder);
        Object curNode = hold.getNext();
        Node cur = new Node(curNode);
       //HERE IS WHERE LOOP STARTS
        while (cur != null && cur != hold && cur != deq.getHead()) {

            Object groundItem = cur;
            final OtherItem groundIt = new OtherItem(groundItem);
            System.out.println("X: " + x + " Y: " + y + " cur: " + cur);
            list.add(new GroundItem(groundIt, x, y));
            curNode = cur.getNext(); //Trying to grab next item
            //stuck in infinite loop now.....
        }
        return list.toArray(new GroundItem[list.size()]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop checks the variable `cur` but you only change the variable `curNode`, so the loop will always handle the same element.

Comment: cur = cur.getNext() gives error, and I can't cast (Node) or else gives error on runtime
type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Node

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: Item cannot be cast to org.ebot.wrappers.Node

Comment: The reason you are stuck inside the loop is beacuse you never advance in the queue on the same variable is used in the while stop condtion.
What does node.getNext() return? 
Check inside the Node constructor and make sure it copies also the links to next node.

Comment: What framework are you using for your Deque and Node? Apparantly not the standard java.util. Can you explain the intention of your code? What is the type of `deque`? Is it already a list or kind of collection?